# In Achievements dialog shows 0 rep change answer is shown

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, achievements-dialog

In the Achievements dialog in the iOS mobile app beta, achievements with 0 rep change are shown.

In this case, it was an answer that was unaccepted and accepted again. On the web application, these changes are filtered out, but not on the mobile app.

[image]

Comment: thanks for reporting, I'll take a look

Comment: your blurs aren't nearly enough. though you'd already made it clear in comments that you'd downvoted "Throw Exception or ignore". As for the other posts, we can see those anyway :)

Comment: It was more to emphasize the post concerning. That info is public so it doesn't matter anyway. My red freehand circles aren't that good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, we were not filtering out those achievements. This behavior will be correct on **version 1.0.1.78**.